# While loop counting down in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to make a `while` loop statement. I was able to make it display 1-10, but I want to get rid of the number 7, but for some reason it won't work.

The `if (counter != 7)` should skip number seven when it displays the numbers from 1-10, but for some reason it won't work.

```
int counter = 1;
while (counter <= 10)
{
    if (counter != 7)
    {
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", counter);
    counter++;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: did you mean count up (instead of countdown)

Comment: @thumbmunkeys oh yeah I mean count Up LOL sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty braces after the if condition don't block the code to reach the Console.WriteLine

```
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter <= 10)   
    {
        if (counter != 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

You should put the write inside the if. It will be executed every time the if(condition) is true

If you feel ready to explore some IEnumerable ways then

```
IEnumerable<int> counters = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
counters.Where(x => x != 7).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Thanks I feel I might be blind LOL

Answer (score 1):

Just put `Console.WriteLine("{0}", counter);` in the right brackets:

```
int counter = 1;
while (counter <= 10)
{
    if (counter != 7)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", counter);
    }
    counter++;
}

Console.ReadLine();
```